# Insert for singly-linked list C

Tags: c, insert, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am having trouble with my insert to the front of the linked list fucntion in C

```
#define arrSIZE = 100;

struct listNode {
    char data[arrSIZE];
    struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode;

void insertHead(ListNode *sPtr, char value[arrSIZE]){
    ListNode *newPtr = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    strncpy(newPtr->data, value, arrSIZE);
    if(sPtr ==NULL){
        newPtr->nextPtr=NULL;
        sPtr = newPtr;
    }else{
        newPtr->nextPtr=sPtr;
        sPtr =newPtr;
    }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: the else statement never gets executed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  This is one more of I don't know how many duplicates — the basic question has been asked (and answered) many times before. Now to try and find a good one.

Comment: Also, note that `#define arrSIZE = 100;` is itself OK, but it means that `char data[arrSIZE];` will not compile because the compiler proper sees `char data[= 100;];` which is clearly syntactically incorrect.  The semicolon at the end is unwanted — it is almost always a mistake if a `#define` ends with a semicolon.  The equals at the start is also almost always a mistake.  You could use it with, for example, `int x arrSIZE` which would initialize `x` correctly, but that isn't the intended use.  `#define arrSIZE 100` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why.
-You're setting sPtr, but sPtr is a local variable and is gone as soon as you exit insertHead.
Instead, you would do this:

```
#define arrSIZE = 100;

struct listNode
{
    char data[arrSIZE];
    struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode;

static ListNode *sPtr = NULL;

void insertHead(char value[arrSIZE])
{
    ListNode *newPtr = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    strncpy(newPtr->data, value, arrSIZE);
    if(sPtr == NULL)
    {
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        sPtr = newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        newPtr->nextPtr = sPtr;
        sPtr = newPtr;
    }
}
```

... Thus you now have a single linked list.

On the other hand, if you want to have more than one linked list, you'll need to add another '*' on the argument:

```
void insertHead(ListNode **aIOPtr , char value[arrSIZE])
{
    if(aIOPtr)
    {
        ListNode *newPtr = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        strncpy(newPtr->data, value, arrSIZE);
        if(*aIOPtr == NULL)
        {
            newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
            *aIOPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            newPtr->nextPtr = sPtr;
            *aIOPtr = newPtr;
        }
    }
}
```