# Ordered Linked List in C causing memory errors?

Tags: c, memory, insert, linked-list

I've written a function

```
void
insertNode(node_t *front, node_t *nodeIn) {
    node_t *currentNode = front;
    node_t *copy;
    if (!(copy = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)))) {
        printf("Out of memory, exiting here?");
        exit(0);
    }   
    strcpy(copy->name, nodeIn->name);
    copy->aisle = nodeIn->aisle;
    copy->shelf = nodeIn->shelf;
    copy->mass = nodeIn->mass;
    copy->price = nodeIn->price;
    copy->quantity = nodeIn->quantity;
    copy->next = NULL;

    if (front == NULL || strcmp(front->name,copy->name) > 0) {
        copy->next = currentNode;
        front = copy;
        printf("%s\n", front->name);
    }
    else {  
        while (currentNode->next != NULL && 
            strcmp((currentNode->next)->name,copy->name) < 0) {
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }
        copy->next = currentNode->next;
        currentNode->next = copy;
    }
}
```

which takes in a pointer to the front node and the node which I want inserted into the list but it is not functioning as intended. Are there any obvious points in my code where it could be breaking?

Comment: `front = copy;` does *nothing* on the caller's passed-in pointer for `front`. The caller's pointer remains unchanged. The problem is essentially *identical* [to **this** question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834117/insert-for-singly-linked-list-c?rq=1), found in the list on the right of this page, though there are better ways to solve it than that.

Comment: Welcome on SO. What exactly do you mean by _"it is not functioning as intended"_? Do you get a specific error message or something like that? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: At another point in my program, there is an 'Exiting, out of memory' statement, that does not trigger if I comment out this function so I figured there must be something wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param front Might be changed upon insertion in front
 * @param nodeIn payload to insert; will neither be changed,
 *               nor used in the list
 */
void
insertNode(node_t **front, node_t *nodeIn) {
    node_t *copy;
    if (!(copy = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t)))) {
        printf("Out of memory, exiting here?");
        exit(0);
    }   
    copy->name = strdup(nodeIn->name);
    copy->aisle = nodeIn->aisle;
    copy->shelf = nodeIn->shelf;
    copy->mass = nodeIn->mass;
    copy->price = nodeIn->price;
    copy->quantity = nodeIn->quantity;

    node_t **currentNode = front;
    while (*currentNode != NULL && strcmp((*currentNode)->name, copy->name) < 0) {
        currentNode = &(*currentNode)->next;
    }
    copy->next = *currentNode;
    *currentNode = copy;
}
```

- The `front` pointer is an in-out parameter as it might be changed when inserting in front.
- The `name` is not allocated, `strdup` makes a string duplicate.
- `currentNode` is an alias. It allows to change the front variable, or some next field.
- The wile-loop positions the currentNode on the right variable.

Deletion should also free name.

Usage:

```
node_t *list = NULL;
node_t data;

data.name = "unu";
...
insertNode(&list, &data);
data.name = "du";
...
insertNode(&list, &data);
data.name = "tri";
...
insertNode(&list, &data);
```

Comment: `strcmp((*currentNode)->next->name, copy->name) < 0) {` currentnode-> next could be NULL here ...

Comment: @joop too: thanks, copy error, original code worked on a `node_t*->next`.